# Break doesn't seem to break the for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, break

My for-loop doesn't seem to break the for-loop and move on to the next d value. It takes 0.5 seconds when the range is 10000 but 0.8 when its 100000? But the range shouldn't matter when it should break long before getting above 100.
Here's my code:

```
import math

d = 1
l = {}

while d < 10:
    for y in range(0, 10000):
        x = y * math.sqrt(d)
        x = round(x)
        if x**2 - (d * y**2) == 1:
            l[d] = x
            print("x: " + str(x) + " d: " + str(d) + " y: " + str(y))
            break
    d += 1

m = max(l, key=l.get)

print("d", m, " :-:  x", l[m])
```

And here's what it outputs:

```
x: 3 d: 2 y: 2
x: 2 d: 3 y: 1
x: 9 d: 5 y: 4
x: 5 d: 6 y: 2
x: 8 d: 7 y: 3
x: 3 d: 8 y: 1
d 5  :-:  x 9

>[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Comment: `break` is working just fine, but you start a new loop each `while` iteration.

Comment: Oh you're right i didn't notice it only outputtet six results instead of the ten it should output.

Comment: The `while` loop iterates *nine* times (1 through to 9). So for `d in {1, 4, 9}` there doesn't appear to be any point where `x**2 - (d * y**2) == 1`  is true, and the full range is tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `break` is working just fine. However, you didn't find a solution for all values of `d`.

Add an `else:` suite to the `for` loop to show when no `break` was executed for that loop:

```
while d < 10:
    for y in range(0, 10000):
        x = y * math.sqrt(d)
        x = round(x)
        if x**2 - (d * y**2) == 1:
            l[d] = x
            print("x: " + str(x) + " d: " + str(d) + " y: " + str(y))
            break
    else:
        print('No solution for d:', d)
    d += 1
```

which outputs:

```
No solution for d: 1
x: 3 d: 2 y: 2
x: 2 d: 3 y: 1
No solution for d: 4
x: 9 d: 5 y: 4
x: 5 d: 6 y: 2
x: 8 d: 7 y: 3
x: 3 d: 8 y: 1
No solution for d: 9
```

The `while` loop could just as well be replaced by a `for d in range(1, 10):`, by the way.